# Java: how to calculate sha1 digest on-the-fly on a stream that is being saved?

Tags: java, stream, digest

I have a servlet written in Java that accepts a multpart-form posted file that needs to be saved in MongoDb/GridFS. I already have the code working for this.

Here is a code fragment that shows how it is done using the org.apache.commons.fileupload package. It consumes almost no memory, because it does not keep too much data in memory.

```
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(req);
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream item = iter.next();
            String name = item.getFieldName();
            InputStream stream = item.openStream();
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                toProcess.put(name, Streams.asString(stream));
            } else {
                String fileName = item.getName();
                String contentType = item.getHeaders().getHeader("Content-Type");
                GridFSUploadOptions options = new GridFSUploadOptions()
                        // .chunkSizeBytes(358400)
                        .metadata(new Document("content_type", contentType));
                ObjectId fileId = gridFSFilesBucket.uploadFromStream(fileName, stream, options);
                fileIds.add(fileId);
                fileNames.add(fileName);
            }
```

I also need to calculate sha1 hash values for all files. Apache digestutils could be used for this. It has a method that can calculate sha1 on a stream:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha1-java.io.InputStream-

My problem is that this method consumes the stream entirely. I need to split the input stream into two parts.  Feed one part into SHA-1 calculation and the other part into the GridFS bucket.

How can I do that? I was thinking about creating my own "pipe" that has an input and an output stream, forwards all data but updates the digest on the fly.

I just don't know how to start writting such a pipe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [Java API class `DigestInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/DigestInputStream.html)

As the Javadoc explains,

> A transparent stream that updates the associated message digest using
>   the bits going through the stream.
>
> To complete the message digest
>   computation, call one of the digest methods on the associated message
>   digest after your calls to one of this digest input stream's read
>   methods.

In your code you can do this:

```
InputStream stream = item.openStream();
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
stream = new DigestInputStream(stream, digest);
```

And at the end you can get the digest with:

```
byte[] hash = digest.digest();
```